# Go GRPC Refresh token for a bidirectional stream

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

**TLDR**: I am looking for a way to update headers on an open stream for each call to `stream.Send(msg)` without closing the stream and opening a new one.

**Summary**

I have a GRPC client and server built to handle bidirectional streams. To authenticate with the server the client must send a JWT in the request headers, set as "authorization". The token is valid for 30 minutes. After the token has expired, the server will terminate the connection.

I am looking for a way to refresh my authorization token from the client, and keep the stream open. The client should run in a loop executing a new request every 30 minutes with the updated token, and the updated payload. I have not seen a way to update a header from the client side for an already opened stream.

Let's look at some code to get an idea of what the client side looks like. The code below has a function to create a new instance of the client, and another function to establish the connection to the GRPC server.

```golang
func NewWatchClient(config *Config, logger *logrus.Logger) (*WatchClient, error) {
    cc, err := newConnection(config, logger)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    service := proto.NewWatchServiceClient(cc)

    return &WatchClient{
        config:  config,
        conn:    cc,
        logger:  entry,
        service: service,
    }, nil
}

func newConnection(config *Config, logger *logrus.Logger) (*grpc.ClientConn, error) {
    address := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", config.Host, config.Port)

    // rpcCredential implements credentials.PerRPCCredentials
    rpcCredential := newTokenAuth(config.Auth, config.TenantID)

    return grpc.Dial(
        address,
        grpc.WithPerRPCCredentials(rpcCredential),
    )
}
```

Looking at the `newConnection` function above I can see that there is a call to another function, `newTokenAuth`, to create an auth token. This func returns a struct that implements the [PerRPCCredentials](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.41.0/credentials#PerRPCCredentials) interface.

There are two ways to set the authorization for a request.

1. Use [grpc.WithPerRPCCredentials](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc#WithPerRPCCredentials) to add the authorization at the time of creating the connection to the server.
2. Use [grpc.PerRPCCredentials](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc#PerRPCCredentials) to add the authorization to each stream opened on the connection to the server.

In this case, I am using `grpc.WithPerRPCCredentials` to attach the token at the time of creating the connection to the server.

Now, let's take a look at the definition of [PerRPCCredentials](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.41.0/credentials#PerRPCCredentials).

```golang
type PerRPCCredentials interface {
    // GetRequestMetadata gets the current request metadata, refreshing
    // tokens if required. This should be called by the transport layer on
    // each request, and the data should be populated in headers or other
    // context. If a status code is returned, it will be used as the status
    // for the RPC. uri is the URI of the entry point for the request.
    // When supported by the underlying implementation, ctx can be used for
    // timeout and cancellation. Additionally, RequestInfo data will be
    // available via ctx to this call.
    // TODO(zhaoq): Define the set of the qualified keys instead of leaving
    // it as an arbitrary string.
    GetRequestMetadata(ctx context.Context, uri ...string) (map[string]string, error)
    // RequireTransportSecurity indicates whether the credentials requires
    // transport security.
    RequireTransportSecurity() bool
}
```

The interface requires that you define two methods. The documentation of `GetRequestMetadata` says

> GetRequestMetadata gets the current request metadata, refreshing tokens if required

So, it looks like my implementation of `PerRPCCredentials` should be able to handle a token refresh for my stream or connection. Let's take a look at my implementation of `PerRPCCredentials`.

```golang
// tokenAuth implements the PerRPCCredentials interface
type tokenAuth struct {
    tenantID       string
    tokenRequester auth.PlatformTokenGetter
    token          string
}

// RequireTransportSecurity leave as false for now
func (tokenAuth) RequireTransportSecurity() bool {
    return false
}

// GetRequestMetadata sets the http header prior to transport
func (t tokenAuth) GetRequestMetadata(_ context.Context, _ ...string) (map[string]string, error) {
    token, err := t.tokenRequester.GetToken()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    t.token = token

    go func() {
        time.Sleep(25 * time.Minute)
        token, _ := t.tokenRequester.GetToken()
        t.token = token
    }()

    return map[string]string{
        "tenant-id": t.tenantID,
        "authorization":     "Bearer " + t.token,
    }, nil
}
```

As you can see, the call to `GetRequestMetadata` will establish a go routine that will attempt to refresh a token every 25 minutes. Adding a go routine right here is probably not the right way to do it. It was an attempt to get the auth header to refresh, which doesn't work.

Let's take a look at the stream.

```golang
func (w WatchClient) CreateWatch() error {
    topic := &proto.Request{SelfLink: w.config.TopicSelfLink}

    stream, err := w.service.CreateWatch(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    for {
        err = stream.Send(topic)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        time.Sleep(25 * time.Minute)
    }
}
```

The client sends a message on the stream every 25 minutes. All I'm looking to get here is that when `stream.Send` is called, the updated token is also sent.

This function, `GetRequestMetadata` only gets called once, regardless if I am setting the auth through `grpc.WithPerRPCCredentials` or `grpc.PerRPCCredsCallOption` so there appears to be no way to update the authorization header.

If you have any idea what I have missed in my attempt to utilize the `PerRPCCredentials` for token refresh then please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Headers are sent at the beginning of an RPC, and cannot be updated during the RPC.  If you need to send data during the life of a stream, it needs to be part of the request message in your proto definition.

Comment: Addittionally, authentication should be performed at the beginning of a call, and then user/client information should be stored in the context and used for whole operation, or sequence of operations. Authentication is used to verify identity of a client, and it doesn't make sense to change client identity during execution of call or during a long running connection/stream. Also it's easier to just cancel and establish a new connection to change identity.